# react-native-camera for iOS doesn't work with latest react-native v0.49

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

i'm trying to build my project on XCode with IPhone 6 IOS v11.0 in react native latest version v0.49 after installing react-native-camera and it failed.
I get the error

> Redefinition of 'RCTMethodInfo'

```
  typedef struct RCTMethodInfo {
  const char *const jsName;
  const char *const objcName;
  const BOOL isSync;
} RCTMethodInfo;
```

[image: screenshot camera]

Comment: I recommend posting this to repo issues instead of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, I hope it would help you out

Just open project in Xcode and search globally for "RCTBridgeModule.h" 
 and you will get 4 to 5 files , so just open your third party camera file 
and replace

```
import "RCTBridgeModule.h" with #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

Comment: thanks but it already have these imports #import and still get the error.